# Cant find stylesheet to import error font-awsome in laravel 5.8

Tags: css, sass, font-awesome, laravel-mix

I created a laravel project using some free bootstrap admin panel and I want to add fontawsome font in my project using a package manager. I read the documentation about it and I followed it correctly but when I do `npm run dev` it gets me an error of `Can't find stylesheet to import.
 @import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free";`. I can saw the folder of `fontawsome` and `@fortawsome` in the `node_modules` folder but when I `crtl+click` some of the import statement, it shows that the file cant be found. Can someone help me with this? I am using the latest version of fontawsome and 5.8 version of laravel.

app.scss

```
// Fonts
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito');

// Variables
@import 'variables';
$fa-font-path:        "../webfonts";

@import "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss";
// Bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
// adminlte
@import '~admin-lte/dist/css/adminlte.css';

@import "~@fortawsome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss";
@import "~@fortawsome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss";
@import "~@fortawsome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands.scss";
```

package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.9.0",
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "admin-lte": "^2.4.15"

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. It was a typo error. I wrote `fortawsome` instead of `fortawesome`.

Comment: Did something similar and just the fact that you mentioned it was a typo allowed me to see my typo as well and fix it. Thanks.